# open context menu on back pressed

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I have an application linked with a DB, for which I need to open a menu with options of save, exit and cancel when the back button is pressed. The menu is already created, and it works (is used with a listview), but I don't know how to use it with the `onbackpressed` method. Any suggestion?

first:

```
    registerForContextMenu(listview);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            openContextMenu(listview);
        }

    });
```

then:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.MenuSospechosoQuestion);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_borrar_sospechoso, menu);
}
```

finally:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.sospBorrar:

          conex = new Conexion(this);
          conex.conectar();
          conex.actualizar("DELETE FROM SOSPECHOSOS WHERE ID_SOSPECHOSO = " + (ids.get(pos)));
          ids.remove(pos);
          names.remove(pos);
          llenarLista();
          conex.desconectar();

         return true;
      case R.id.sosEditar:
          intent = new Intent(DenunciaMenuSuspect.this, Suspect.class);
            intent.putExtra("toUpdate", true);
            intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(ids.get(pos)));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

         return true;
      case R.id.cancelar:
         return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a design problem.  Personally, this is not how I expect a mobile app to work and apps that change the standard behaviour are annoying.  What does `exit` mean?  That's what the back button is for!

Comment: Yes, I want that the exit button do that, exit, but, I want that the user have the option to save before do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use dialog instead menu .

```
private AlertDialog dialog;
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if(dialog == null)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
        builder.setPositiveButton("save",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //save your data
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("exit",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setTitle("Are you sure?");
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed(); // or dialog.dismiss();
        dialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I make of that way the users only will have the option of save or exit, not the option of stay on current section.

Comment: @user2904714 see i've edited answer , now users can stay on current section (just press back again for close dialog)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to override the onBackPressed method of your activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Do what you want
}
```

**Edit:** the dooplaye's answer is a good way.

You can set a custom View to the AlertDialog.Builder like this:

```
builder.setView('yourListView');
```

Comment: my listview works fine, the problem is how implement this behaviour to a backpressed

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
    this.getWindow().openPanel(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL, event);
}
```